# Using adverb clauses of time correctly

Tags: clauses

Is it always possible to move an adverb clause within a sentence? Are both of the following sentences correct?

```
When/after she had left, I sat to write.
I sat to write when/after she had left.
```

Comment: Both are fine. But just remember we sit DOWN to write, though infuriatingly we sit an exam!

Comment: I find nothing wrong with "sat to write". It strikes me as perhaps someone's stylistic preference rather than a standard of good writing.

Comment: @WS2: We only "sit an exam" in BrE.

Comment: The "had" is superfluous here, unless you have a specific reason to include it. But I can't think of what that might be.

Comment: @Robusto Sorry I'd forgotten that only we 'sit an exam'. And my magistrate friend 'sits in Reading', not on the pavement but on the Bench. Australians and South Africans 'write an exam'. I don't know what Americans do.

Comment: @JimReynolds The most recent example the OED has of anyone using *sit to (verb)* without a *down* in between is from 1817, when the Prince Regent ruled in Britain and James Madison was President - no doubt 'sitting to his work in the Oval Office'.

Comment: We Americans take exams. (And never give them back.) It's perhaps another British/American thing. 

"That case would become the subject for our nonfiction expos, The Cyanide Canary. This time, however, when I sat to write, I was armed with all of my hard work." -- Date: 2010 Publication information: Feb 2010, Vol. 123 Issue 2, p13-47, 3p Title: Don't be afraid of striking out: In writing, as in baseball, you have to stick with it to hit one out of the park. Author: Dugoni, Robert Source: Writer (academic journal).

Comment: Also in 2010: Elizabeth was Queen of Jamaica, Barbados, the Bahamas, Grenada, Papua New Guinea, Solomon Islands, Tuvalu, Saint Lucia, Saint Vincent and the Grenadines, Belize, Antigua and Barbuda, and Saint Kitts and Nevis. Barack Obama and the First Lady hosted a concert honoring Sir Paul McCartney. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.

In your first sentence, you want to say **what you did** after she had left.

In the second sentence you want to say **when you sat down** to write.

In the same way, you could say:

> "After I had warned them of possible danger, I walked back home."
>
> or
>
> "I walked back home after I had warned them of possible danger."

Comment: In the first case, *after* has a connotation of 'as a consequence of.'

Answer (score 0):

I prefer `after` in both of these cases cases because `after` signifies an ordering of events. First she left, then you sat to write. There is a temporal ordering to the events, so I think `after` is much better.

Also I think `sat to write` is a bit strange.

Comment: Those are good reasons not to use them yourself. On the other hand, being personal tastes, they're kind of irrelevant to questions of grammar or usage in general. When discussing the electromagnetic spectrum, few are likely to be interested in which colors are your favorites.